# LG K10 2017 M250E deleted partitions

Tags: unbricking, lg, mediatek

I wanted restore factory settings. Unfortunately I erased partitions in fastboot mode. Now the device is showing only the LG boot logo and keeps rebooting.  I don't have access to fastboot mode and download mode. I probably need scatter file and flash new ROM with SP Flash tool, but i can't do this scatter file.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look for LG K10 2017 M250E ROM firmware dump online. I did a quick google and found a few. Notably: http://www.lgstockrom.com/lg-k10-2010-m250e. The results in a .kdz file that requires special software to open. That software is specific to LG and was easily located online. There's no other way that I know of to recover those partitions.

Comment: I have a ROM stock file. I unpacked it and received several .bin files. But I think I need partition images and a scatter file from a working phone. SP Flash Tool requires .IMG files and I have .bin from .kdz files :/

Comment: Ah I see. There's a easier way using LG Flash tool instead of SP Flash tool. http://www.androidmtk.com/use-lg-flash-tool. I apologize I just assumed the kdz file would result in a scatter file with your partitions. You can convert BIN to ISO but using the link in this comment, a step by step how to flash the kdz file using LG Flash Tool, is much more straight forward.

Comment: I have no access to "download mode" and LG Flash tool requires access to "download mode" :/ When I try to put the phone in this mode I get a message "Your device is corrupt. It can't be trusted and may not work properly"

Comment: Are you able to boot to recovery? Turn off phone then press and hold the power and volume down buttons until the LG logo is displayed. If you can get into recovery wipe and factory reset. I want to assume you already did this. If it's boot looping it's a soft brick so it may just need to wipe cached data.

Comment: If above does not work what partitions did you delete?

Comment: I managed to use WinBin2Iso to create images of both the boot and recovery from the BIN files. Generating the scatter file may be possible with MTK Droid Tools but I don't know for sure. I can look more into it tomorrow. This is a bit beyond my knowledge but I'm happy to continue to help in any way I can.

Comment: I can't get into recovery mode now. It probably removed. Before removed it, i choose "wipe cache partition". The phone was still in bootloop. Then I choose "wipe data/factory reset" option. After that recovery mode is not available

Comment: Have you tried using the keys to access download mode? **Power** + **Volume Down** + **Home** while powered down?

Comment: You can also try powering down, hold **Volume up** + **Volume Down** + **Power** + **Insert USB Cable**

Comment: That's working on the MediaTek MT6750 processor correct?

Comment: If that's correct I know how to get your scatter file and we can see what partitions are missing.

Comment: "Power + Volume Down + Home" doesn't work, because I don't have a Home button.

Comment: "Volume up + Volume Down + Power + USB Cable" - after that appears screen "IMEI Display". 
Thanks for your interest in the topic.
I think, I have to wait for someone with a similar phone to solve a problem ;

Comment: You should post this issue on XDA Developers forum: https://forum.xda-developers.com/.

Comment: Yeah, I will do that. Thanks for suggestion